# How to have autocompletion with thunderbird inside mail

Tags: thunderbird

When I use vim, I have autocompletion with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>N</kbd>, with netbeans, it's <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd>.
I «want» this feature with Thunderbird. How can I do it?

Note. I don't speak about autocomplete addresses.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is not perfect but if you like vim maybe it is ok for you:
use the extension [External Editor](http://globs.org/articles.php?lng=en&pg=2)

There you can define which editor is opened for editing your mails. In the properties of the Extension set

```
xterm -e vim
```

to use vim. Then you have your autocompletion just like always in vim.

Comment: I must set only `xterm -e vim` and, if i try `gvim` it's fail :-(

Comment: did you try to set `gvim --nofork`?

Comment: Mmh this is one solution ,-)